# Am I writing good Go here? Python functions converted to Go

Tags: python, go

*I originally asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039172/seeking-the-right-ways-to-convert-these-two-python-functions-to-go) on StackOverflow. Reproduced here by recommendation.*

I've got a number of Python scripts that I'm considering converting to Go. I'm seeking confirmation that I'm using Go in essentially the way it was meant to be used. Full code is available here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7521526

**So the primary question is: Am I writing what is considered "good Go" ?**

**Python function #1**: Look at the files in a folder and extract the latest encoded date in the filenames.

```
def retrieveLatestDateSuffix(target):
    return max(map("".join, filter(lambda x: x, 
        map(lambda x: re.findall(r"_([0-9]{8})\.txt$", x), 
            os.listdir(target)))))
```

My translation for #1:

```
var rldsPat = regexp.MustCompile(`_([0-9]{8})\.txt$`)
func retrieveLatestDateSuffix(target string) (string, error) {
    if fis, e := ioutil.ReadDir(target); e == nil {
        t := ""
        for _, fi := range fis {
            if m := rldsPat.FindStringSubmatch(fi.Name()); m != nil {
                if m[1] > t { t = m[1] }
            }
        }
        return t, nil
    } else {
        return "", e
    }
}
```

**Python function #2**: Add a date suffix to each filename inside a folder that doesn't already have a suffix added. Printing the from/to for now instead of doing the rename.

```
def addDateSuffix(target, suffix):
    for fn in filter(lambda x: re.search(r"(?<!_[0-9]{8})\.txt$", x), os.listdir(target)):
        pref, ext = os.path.splitext(fn)
        gn = "{0}_{1}{2}".format(pref, suffix, ext)
        print(fn, " -> ", gn)
```

My translation for #2:

```
var adsPat1 = regexp.MustCompile(`\.txt$`)
var adsPat2 = regexp.MustCompile(`_[0-9]{8}\.txt$`)
func addDateSuffix(target string, suffix string) error {
    if fis, e := ioutil.ReadDir(target); e == nil {
        for _, fi := range fis {
            if m1 := adsPat1.FindStringSubmatch(fi.Name()); m1 != nil {
                if m2 := adsPat2.FindStringSubmatch(fi.Name()); m2 == nil {
                    ext := filepath.Ext(fi.Name())
                    gn := fmt.Sprintf("%s_%s%s", strings.TrimSuffix(fi.Name(), ext), suffix, ext)
                    fmt.Println(fi.Name(), "->", gn)
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    } else {
        return e
    }
}
```

Comment: `rldsPat, `adsPat1`, `adsPat2` - `wtfPat`? Plse dnt try to sve lttrs n vribl nms :)

Comment: Just saw another post of this and your comment on it. To your bigger question of whether you should be using Go here, agree with your "maybe not". I can't tell if this is part of an app or standalone, but at least the task of adding and reading date suffixes on filenames is a great fit for Python/Perl; much as I like Go, I don't see much advantage to using Go for this task. (On the other hand, an app that needed or wanted lower-level bit-slinging, more direct OS access, concurrency, etc. might fit with Go's strengths.)

Answer (score 5):

Early return is better than nesting. For example:

```
var adsPat1 = regexp.MustCompile(`\.txt$`)
var adsPat2 = regexp.MustCompile(`_[0-9]{8}\.txt$`)
func addDateSuffix(target string, suffix string) error {
    fis, e := ioutil.ReadDir(target)
    if e != nil {
        return e
    }
    for _, fi := range fis {
        if m1 := adsPat1.FindStringSubmatch(fi.Name()); m1 == nil {
            continue
        }
        if m2 := adsPat2.FindStringSubmatch(fi.Name()); m2 != nil {
            continue
        }
        ext := filepath.Ext(fi.Name())
        gn := fmt.Sprintf("%s_%s%s", strings.TrimSuffix(fi.Name(), ext), suffix, ext)
        fmt.Println(fi.Name(), "->", gn)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Also see this post for more idiomatic go discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028579/what-is-the-idiomatic-version-of-this-function

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script with both functions. Changes I made:

- `strings.HasSuffix` will do to test for `/\.txt$/`.
- `os.Open`ing the dir and calling `Readdirnames` is shorter.
- `dateSuffixPat.MatchString` is all `addDateSuffix` needs.
- I used named return values like Jared did.
- `dateSuffixPat` is a more descriptive name.
- I used a string slice to cut off `.txt`; unsure if I think it's better, but it's shorter.

You could make further changes, like changing the APIs of these funcs to make a directory that's already been `os.Open`'d, or even just have them accept the list of names from `Readdirnames`; then you avoid repeating the `os` calls and error checks.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

var dateSuffixPat = regexp.MustCompile(`_([0-9]{8})\.txt$`)

const ext = ".txt"

func addDateSuffix(dirname string, suffix string) (err error) {
    dir, err := os.Open(dirname)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fns, err := dir.Readdirnames(0)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    for _, fn := range fns {
        if !strings.HasSuffix(fn, ext) || dateSuffixPat.MatchString(fn) {
            continue
        }
        datedFn := fmt.Sprintf("%s_%s%s", fn[:len(fn)-len(ext)], suffix, ext)
        fmt.Println(fn, "->", datedFn)
    }
    return
}

func retrieveLatestDateSuffix(dirname string) (latest string, err error) {
    dir, err := os.Open(dirname)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fns, err := dir.Readdirnames(0)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    for _, fn := range fns {
        if m := dateSuffixPat.FindStringSubmatch(fn); m != nil {
            if m[1] > latest {
                latest = m[1]
            }
        }
    }
    return
}

const dir = "."

func main() {
    err := addDateSuffix(dir, "19920101")
    if err != nil {
        // you would rarely panic in real life, but toy script, fine
        panic(err)
    }
    latest, err := retrieveLatestDateSuffix(dir)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(latest)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Go is just going to be longer than python for a lot of stuff. You can do some cool stuff with it, though. :)

Comment: And, not to bug, but there are a [couple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028579/what-is-the-idiomatic-version-of-this-function) related [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026320/go-how-to-tell-if-folder-is-writable) over on SO with answers with upvotes that you haven't accepted. Might be worth accepting or clarifying why you don't think the question's been answered, depending on what you think. (Conflict-of-interest disclosure--I answered one of them.)